# Running setInterval() inside React function happens multiple times and increases the amount rapidly over time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Check the console inside this sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-thunder-c71ov?file=/src/App.js

```
function Subjects({ logoArray }) {
  const item1 = useRef();
  const item2 = useRef();
  const item3 = useRef();
  const item4 = useRef();

  const [images, setImages] = useState({ arr: logoArray, hasmoved: 0 });

  setInterval(() => {
    let randomChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
    let randomSwitch =
      Math.floor(Math.random() * (images.arr.length - 1 - 4 + 1)) + 4;

    // Handle Randomchoice
    if (randomChoice === images.hasmoved) {
      if (images.hasmoved === 3) randomChoice--;
      else randomChoice++;
    }

    let updatedArray = images.arr;

    let changeThis = updatedArray[randomChoice];
    let switchThis = updatedArray[randomSwitch];

    updatedArray[randomChoice] = switchThis;
    updatedArray[randomSwitch] = changeThis;

    setImages({ arr: updatedArray, hasmoved: randomChoice });

    console.log("Happened");
  }, 5000);

  const handleTransition = (ev, n) => {};

  return (
    <>
      <li
        ref={item1}
        onTransitionEnd={(ev) => handleTransition(ev, item1)}
        className="bar-item"
      ></li>
      <li
        ref={item2}
        onTransitionEnd={(ev) => handleTransition(ev, item2)}
        className="bar-item"
      ></li>
      <li
        ref={item3}
        onTransitionEnd={(ev) => handleTransition(ev, item3)}
        className="bar-item"
      ></li>
      <li
        ref={item4}
        onTransitionEnd={(ev) => handleTransition(ev, item4)}
        className="bar-item"
      ></li>
    </>
  );
}
```

Every time "happened" is logged to the console my `setInterval()` function has completed, but it's only supposed to run once every five second.

Can anyone explain to me, why this happens and possibly come up with a solution?

Comment: Every time `Subject` rerenders you are creating an additional interval, i.e. you will have more and more intervals running at the same time. Have a look at https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone visiting this answer in the future... I fixed it and even added the transitionHandler, enjoy :)

```
function Subjects({ logoArray }) {

    const item1 = useRef();
    const item2 = useRef();
    const item3 = useRef();
    const item4 = useRef();

    const [images, setImages] = useState({ arr: logoArray })

    const dissapear = "activeOut";
    const appear = "activeIn";

    const handleTransition = (ev, item, index) => {
        if (item.current.classList.contains(dissapear)) {

            let randomSwitch = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((images.arr.length - 1) - 4 + 1)) + 4;

            let updatedArray = images.arr;

            let changeThis = updatedArray[index];
            let switchThis = updatedArray[randomSwitch];

            updatedArray[index] = switchThis;
            updatedArray[randomSwitch] = changeThis;

            setImages({ arr: updatedArray });

            item.current.classList.replace(dissapear, appear);

        } else if (item.current.classList.contains(appear)) item.current.classList.remove(appear);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            let randomChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * (Math.floor(3) - Math.ceil(0) + 1)) + Math.ceil(0);

            if (randomChoice == 0) item1.current.classList.add(dissapear);
            if (randomChoice == 1) item2.current.classList.add(dissapear);
            if (randomChoice == 2) item3.current.classList.add(dissapear);
            if (randomChoice == 3) item4.current.classList.add(dissapear);
        }, 5000);
        return () => {
            clearInterval(interval);
        };
    }, []);


    return (
        <>
            <li ref={item1} onTransitionEnd={ev => handleTransition(ev, item1, 0)} className="bar-item">
                {images.arr[0]}
            </li>
            <li ref={item2} onTransitionEnd={ev => handleTransition(ev, item2, 1)} className="bar-item">
                {images.arr[1]}
            </li>
            <li ref={item3} onTransitionEnd={ev => handleTransition(ev, item3, 2)} className="bar-item">
                {images.arr[2]}
            </li>
            <li ref={item4} onTransitionEnd={ev => handleTransition(ev, item4, 3)} className="bar-item">
                {images.arr[3]}
            </li>
        </>
    )

}
```